# How to plot the frequency of multiple groups of yearly data from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to display a comparison visual of movies and series from a dataframe downloaded from kaggale.Please see first image. The issue is the graph, the graph is only displaying the xticks, grid, title, xlabel, ylabel and legend and not the visual comparison of movies and series. The histogram is not displaying.

column `'type'` contains: `['movie' 'series' 'episode']`

My Columns

```
imdb_id        0
title          0
type           0
rated          0
year           0
released_at    0
added_at       0
runtime        0
genre          0
director       0
metascore      0
imdb_rating    0
imdb_votes     0
awards         0
writer         0
actors         0
country        0
```

[null data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHgQ8.png)

My CODE:

```
disney_movie = df[df['type'] == 'movie']
disney_tv = df[df['type'] == 'series']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(disney_movie['movie'], label='Movie')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(disney_tv['series'], label='TV Show')

plt.xticks(bins)
plt.grid(axis='x', lw = 0.5)

plt.title('movies vs seres')
plt.xlabel('type')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here is a subset of relevant data from [kaggle: Disney Plus Movies and TV Shows](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/unanimad/disney-plus-shows)

```
type,released_at
movie,31 Mar 1999
series,25 Mar 2019
movie,27 Nov 1996
movie,21 Jan 2003
movie,22 Nov 2000
movie,11 Dec 2011
movie,20 Jul 1955
movie,25 Nov 1998
movie,10 Apr 2020
movie,07 Apr 1995
movie,11 Aug 1995
movie,08 Mar 1946
movie,23 Aug 2002
movie,22 Jun 1977
movie,09 Mar 2018
movie,24 May 2019
movie,25 Nov 1992
movie,13 Aug 1996
movie,20 May 1994
movie,14 Sep 1951
movie,05 Mar 2010
movie,25 Aug 2005
movie,02 Sep 1949
movie,18 Mar 2000
movie,26 Sep 1962
series,26 Nov 1989
movie,02 Jul 2004
series,06 Dec 2015
movie,20 Mar 1981
movie,29 Feb 2000
series,10 Mar 2017
movie,07 Nov 1999
movie,07 Jul 2019
movie,16 Jun 2004
movie,29 Jan 2017
movie,20 May 2003
movie,22 Jun 2001
movie,06 Nov 2018
series,02 Dec 2011
movie,18 Dec 2009
movie,19 Nov 1932
movie,14 Dec 1961
movie,21 Aug 1942
movie,07 Feb 2006
movie,15 Jun 2018
series,27 Mar 2020
movie,09 Jun 1939
movie,19 Aug 1955
movie,22 Nov 1991
movie,16 Feb 1998
movie,11 Nov 1997
movie,18 Feb 2005
movie,13 Dec 1971
movie,25 Dec 2008
movie,02 Sep 1955
movie,30 Oct 2016
movie,19 Jun 1987
series,26 Jun 2015
movie,10 Jun 1988
series,18 Jun 2018
movie,07 Nov 2014
movie,11 Oct 2009
movie,08 Feb 1968
movie,11 Feb 1994
series,09 Sep 2019
movie,25 Feb 1938
movie,21 Nov 2008
series,04 Sep 1993
movie,05 Nov 2004
series,24 Sep 1993
series,09 Oct 2011
movie,22 Jun 2012
movie,24 May 1999
movie,20 Sep 2017
movie,29 Aug 1998
movie,07 Nov 2003
movie,29 Aug 2006
movie,11 Mar 2005
series,16 Jul 2018
movie,18 Nov 2008
movie,08 Mar 2002
movie,26 Aug 1994
movie,20 Jun 2008
movie,03 Sep 2010
movie,10 Apr 1999
movie,16 Dec 1977
movie,30 May 1941
movie,09 Jun 2006
movie,24 Jun 2011
movie,16 Jun 2017
episode,29 Oct 2008
episode,02 Nov 2010
episode,27 Oct 2008
episode,22 Mar 2013
episode,04 Jun 2012
movie,12 Dec 2008
episode,20 Nov 2009
episode,22 Mar 2013
episode,25 May 1986
movie,25 Dec 2003
movie,18 Aug 1989
movie,05 Dec 1941
movie,04 Nov 2005
series,04 Mar 1989
movie,28 Nov 1947
movie,04 Mar 1950
movie,26 Feb 2002
movie,06 Feb 2007
movie,15 Oct 1937
movie,17 Jan 2014
movie,22 Nov 2017
movie,07 Mar 2008
movie,20 Feb 2004
series,15 Nov 2016
movie,01 Oct 1993
movie,23 Mar 1951
movie,24 Mar 2006
series,01 Oct 2012
movie,16 Feb 2009
movie,22 Jun 1960
series,06 Sep 1991
movie,18 Jul 1956
movie,25 May 1955
movie,18 Jun 2010
movie,18 Dec 2017
movie,29 Jan 2004
movie,21 Jul 2017
movie,02 Aug 2019
movie,05 Aug 2003
movie,14 Aug 2017
series,17 Jan 2020
movie,19 Mar 2010
movie,19 May 2000
movie,17 Jun 2016
series,14 Jun 2019
movie,12 Nov 2010
movie,13 Feb 2015
series,20 Nov 2017
series,24 Jun 2016
movie,13 Aug 2010
movie,31 Jul 2015
series,18 Sep 2015
series,17 Oct 2014
series,12 Nov 2019
series,13 Jul 2018
series,15 Feb 2019
movie,12 Oct 2012
series,15 Jun 2012
series,20 Mar 2020
series,14 Feb 2011
series,02 May 2009
series,18 Jan 2015
series,02 Mar 2016
series,12 Nov 2019
series,05 May 2006
series,03 Oct 2016
series,14 Nov 2011
episode,26 Jul 2014
series,13 Aug 2012
series,21 Jul 2017
series,14 Feb 2016
series,03 Dec 2010
series,15 Jan 2016
movie,28 Sep 2018
series,01 Oct 2017
series,14 Sep 1985
series,07 Sep 1996
series,18 Sep 1987
episode,11 Dec 2017
series,31 Aug 1998
series,07 Jun 2002
series,09 Oct 2005
series,06 Sep 1996
series,31 Aug 1997
series,27 Jan 2006
movie,07 Jul 2000
series,11 Sep 1992
movie,22 Apr 2011
movie,18 Apr 2014
movie,21 Apr 2017
movie,20 Apr 2012
movie,25 Sep 2009
movie,17 Apr 2015
movie,17 Apr 2019
movie,16 Apr 2013
movie,03 Apr 2020
series,23 Mar 2012
movie,26 Jun 1998
movie,22 Jun 2001
series,08 Sep 2019
movie,03 Apr 2020
movie,30 May 1953
movie,09 Oct 1999
movie,05 Apr 1940
movie,04 Nov 1938
movie,29 Jan 1943
movie,20 Dec 1946
movie,18 Jan 2002
movie,26 Mar 1999
series,04 Apr 2014
series,13 Oct 2019
movie,16 Jul 1954
movie,19 Dec 2017
movie,07 Dec 2014
movie,01 Dec 2011
movie,19 Sep 2016
series,01 May 2018
series,12 Aug 2017
movie,03 Aug 1990
movie,10 Nov 2009
movie,29 Mar 2019
movie,09 Jul 2017
episode,09 Jun 2009
movie,18 Jul 2003
movie,17 Feb 2006
series,22 Jul 2016
movie,03 Apr 2020
movie,28 Mar 1936
movie,18 Dec 1964
movie,20 Sep 2004
series,12 Nov 2019
movie,21 Mar 1975
series,17 Jun 2000
movie,20 Oct 2019
movie,16 Nov 2016
series,11 Dec 2017
movie,21 Jul 1941
movie,16 Jun 2000
series,24 Sep 1994
movie,25 Nov 1938
movie,17 Jun 2016
movie,30 May 2003
movie,30 Aug 1996
series,28 Aug 2010
movie,01 Aug 1986
movie,12 Nov 2019
movie,30 Jul 1932
movie,26 Nov 1997
movie,02 Nov 2001
episode,03 Jan 2020
episode,10 Jan 2020
movie,20 Oct 1995
movie,05 Oct 2012
movie,21 Dec 1984
movie,21 Jan 1977
movie,06 Aug 2003
movie,10 Aug 2018
movie,13 Dec 2018
movie,13 Jan 2012
movie,27 Nov 2013
movie,22 Nov 2019
movie,21 Nov 2003
movie,12 Mar 1948
movie,18 May 1986
movie,24 Jul 2009
series,24 Oct 1994
movie,11 Nov 2011
movie,21 Aug 1999
movie,16 Jul 1997
movie,20 Oct 2003
movie,25 Nov 1997
movie,20 Jul 2002
series,27 Jun 2014
movie,13 Jan 2006
movie,10 Jun 2005
movie,19 Mar 2004
series,04 Apr 2010
movie,02 Dec 2011
series,05 Sep 1992
series,21 Jul 2019
movie,26 Jul 2002
movie,10 Feb 1934
series,07 Nov 2010
movie,17 Jul 1961
movie,07 Jul 1976
movie,26 Sep 1971
movie,17 Oct 1998
movie,08 Oct 2004
movie,12 Oct 2001
series,24 Mar 2006
movie,01 Feb 2008
movie,10 Apr 2009
movie,24 Apr 2009
movie,24 Sep 1937
movie,17 Feb 1995
series,15 Apr 2013
movie,25 Jun 1980
movie,24 Jun 1977
movie,06 Jun 1974
movie,22 Jun 2005
movie,20 Jun 1997
movie,20 Jan 2006
movie,17 Aug 2007
movie,24 Oct 2008
series,12 Nov 2019
movie,20 Dec 2019
movie,16 Jul 1993
movie,18 Apr 2003
movie,12 Dec 1997
movie,02 Apr 2004
movie,08 Mar 1996
movie,12 Feb 1993
movie,17 Jul 1992
movie,23 Jun 1989
movie,18 Mar 1997
movie,20 Nov 1999
series,01 Apr 2019
movie,01 Apr 2001
movie,17 Apr 2016
movie,15 Aug 2014
movie,04 Dec 1942
movie,04 Sep 1942
movie,15 Sep 1944
movie,23 Oct 1942
series,11 Aug 2013
movie,13 Nov 1998
movie,15 Mar 2002
movie,20 Mar 2016
movie,18 Mar 2005
series,06 Sep 2008
movie,03 Apr 2020
episode,10 Jan 2015
movie,19 Jun 2015
movie,23 Jul 1999
movie,11 Mar 2003
movie,21 Feb 2019
movie,22 Apr 2018
movie,25 Aug 2006
movie,09 Oct 2015
series,24 Sep 1994
movie,14 Jan 1994
movie,09 Aug 1996
movie,11 Jan 2008
movie,12 Apr 1996
movie,24 Nov 2017
series,30 Sep 2011
episode,05 Jan 2013
movie,09 Mar 2012
movie,23 Nov 2007
movie,24 Jul 1999
movie,27 Feb 2009
movie,01 Dec 1959
movie,27 Apr 2007
movie,17 Aug 2001
movie,07 Mar 1997
movie,19 Oct 1960
movie,06 Feb 1972
movie,17 Jul 1996
series,13 Jun 2011
movie,15 Feb 2019
movie,08 Apr 2005
movie,08 Mar 2009
series,25 Aug 2019
movie,18 Feb 2019
movie,13 Dec 2005
movie,22 Jun 2012
movie,12 Nov 2019
movie,22 Jun 1955
movie,27 Feb 2001
movie,08 Feb 1952
movie,31 Jan 2020
series,01 Nov 2016
series,29 Oct 2018
series,06 Jul 2015
series,15 Feb 2016
series,20 Jun 2016
movie,23 Nov 2014
movie,20 Sep 2014
movie,04 May 2014
movie,15 Apr 2011
movie,03 Oct 1941
movie,23 Jun 2006
movie,01 Jun 2012
movie,25 Apr 1952
series,19 May 2013
movie,15 Jul 2005
movie,04 Jun 1993
movie,02 Dec 2018
movie,29 Jun 2007
movie,21 Jun 2002
series,20 Sep 2003
movie,30 Aug 2005
series,12 Jan 2001
movie,24 Dec 1937
movie,10 Jan 2020
series,01 Oct 2019
series,06 Feb 2018
movie,16 Jun 2017
movie,09 Mar 2001
movie,06 Mar 2020
movie,06 Feb 1937
movie,11 Dec 2017
movie,11 Mar 2011
movie,12 Nov 2018
movie,04 Nov 2014
series,19 Nov 1994
series,08 Sep 1996
series,31 Oct 1992
movie,28 Aug 2019
movie,16 Jan 2019
movie,31 Mar 2019
series,13 Aug 2018
movie,11 Oct 2019
movie,18 Dec 2019
movie,30 Sep 2018
movie,18 Mar 2014
movie,17 Jul 2015
movie,01 May 2015
movie,26 Apr 2019
movie,16 Feb 2018
movie,06 May 2016
movie,22 Jul 2011
movie,04 Apr 2014
movie,08 Mar 2019
movie,04 Nov 2016
movie,01 Aug 2014
movie,05 May 2017
movie,02 May 2008
movie,07 May 2010
movie,03 May 2013
movie,04 May 2012
movie,06 May 2011
movie,03 Nov 2017
movie,08 Nov 2013
series,13 Oct 2017
series,01 Apr 2012
series,06 Jan 2015
series,10 Jun 2017
series,26 May 2013
series,22 Jul 2017
series,26 Jul 2015
series,12 Nov 2019
series,29 Sep 2017
movie,03 Dec 2013
series,10 Mar 2017
series,21 Nov 2017
series,29 Jul 2017
movie,18 Jun 1965
movie,25 Oct 2006
movie,27 Mar 1998
movie,30 Mar 2007
movie,27 May 1948
series,12 Mar 2013
series,17 Jul 1955
series,15 Jan 2017
movie,17 Aug 2004
movie,07 Feb 1942
movie,16 Dec 1983
movie,09 Nov 1999
movie,20 Jun 1936
movie,06 May 1938
movie,09 Nov 2004
movie,25 Dec 1998
movie,09 Aug 2002
series,06 Feb 2015
movie,29 Apr 2005
movie,25 Jan 2008
movie,06 Feb 2004
movie,17 May 1998
movie,13 May 2000
movie,05 Jan 2014
movie,02 Oct 1947
movie,19 Nov 2018
movie,23 Nov 2016
movie,13 Oct 2000
movie,21 Jun 2013
movie,02 Nov 2001
movie,16 Feb 2001
episode,20 Apr 1986
movie,07 Jun 1940
movie,01 Nov 1940
movie,19 Jun 1998
movie,17 Dec 2004
series,23 Mar 2018
series,03 Apr 2015
movie,16 Feb 1996
movie,21 Mar 2014
episode,21 Sep 1969
movie,12 Feb 1999
series,12 May 2007
movie,19 Nov 2004
movie,21 Dec 2007
movie,28 Jul 1951
movie,10 Apr 1992
movie,16 Feb 2017
movie,12 Nov 2019
movie,14 Jan 2005
movie,27 Oct 2017
movie,25 Nov 2009
movie,10 Jul 1959
movie,18 Nov 1988
movie,28 Sep 1935
movie,18 Dec 2005
series,03 Dec 2019
movie,25 Jan 1961
movie,22 Nov 1985
movie,06 Jun 2006
series,26 Mar 2018
movie,06 Mar 2020
movie,28 Jul 1995
series,06 Mar 2017
movie,02 Nov 1951
series,07 Oct 1998
series,07 Jul 2019
movie,03 Dec 2018
movie,29 May 2009
movie,21 Mar 2014
movie,03 Apr 2020
movie,28 Aug 1957
movie,03 Nov 1977
movie,12 Aug 2016
movie,05 Feb 1953
movie,15 Feb 2002
movie,10 Nov 2000
series,18 Jun 2004
series,17 Aug 2007
movie,05 Aug 2011
episode,16 Aug 2013
series,20 Dec 2019
movie,21 Mar 2003
movie,23 Feb 1940
movie,17 Jun 2016
movie,25 May 2007
movie,07 Jul 2006
movie,20 May 2011
movie,09 Jul 2003
series,12 Nov 2019
movie,16 Jan 2004
series,18 Sep 2015
movie,21 Nov 1952
movie,19 Sep 1952
movie,09 Jul 1948
movie,23 Jun 1995
movie,25 Aug 1998
movie,19 May 1960
movie,05 Aug 1997
movie,11 Feb 2005
movie,27 Jun 2008
series,21 Jan 2016
movie,26 Jun 2009
movie,29 Apr 2011
movie,23 Jul 1953
series,14 Apr 2017
movie,04 Feb 2019
series,02 Sep 1996
movie,30 Sep 2016
movie,18 Aug 2000
movie,29 Jun 2007
movie,21 Jul 2006
movie,14 Jul 2000
movie,09 Dec 2003
movie,16 Feb 2001
movie,09 Dec 2003
movie,20 Jan 2012
movie,06 Jul 1987
movie,29 Sep 2000
movie,10 Mar 1978
movie,20 Oct 2006
movie,21 Jun 1985
movie,10 Nov 1998
movie,21 Mar 2003
movie,22 Apr 2000
movie,08 Nov 1973
movie,03 Mar 2018
movie,16 Dec 2016
movie,07 Jul 1993
movie,27 Jan 2006
movie,18 Jan 1998
series,28 Jul 2014
movie,22 Apr 2004
movie,06 Feb 1943
episode,28 Oct 1962
movie,25 Nov 2015
movie,20 Nov 2012
movie,10 Dec 1932
movie,20 Dec 2013
movie,19 Oct 2018
movie,01 Jan 2017
movie,30 Jun 1939
movie,14 Dec 2012
movie,08 Oct 2010
movie,03 Dec 2017
movie,06 Nov 1956
movie,10 Apr 2010
series,29 Jul 2018
series,07 Nov 2010
movie,01 Nov 2013
movie,19 Apr 2011
series,20 Jan 2014
movie,01 Mar 1991
series,28 Feb 2020
series,07 Feb 1998
movie,27 Jul 2007
movie,29 May 1992
movie,10 Dec 1993
movie,27 Nov 2009
movie,25 Dec 1959
series,26 Mar 1997
movie,26 Jun 1999
movie,11 Feb 2019
movie,18 Jan 2002
movie,04 Feb 1938
movie,22 Jun 1973
movie,15 Dec 2007
series,18 Jan 1999
movie,03 Feb 1939
series,08 Feb 2009
series,14 Mar 2016
series,12 Sep 1981
series,12 Sep 1981
series,02 Oct 1999
series,22 Sep 1979
movie,09 Mar 1984
series,03 Jul 2017
series,26 Sep 2014
series,01 Oct 2018
movie,25 May 1977
movie,16 May 2002
series,03 May 2017
movie,25 May 1983
movie,19 May 2005
series,03 Oct 2008
movie,15 Aug 2008
movie,20 Jun 1980
movie,18 Dec 2015
movie,15 Dec 2017
movie,19 May 1999
movie,13 Mar 2020
movie,14 Feb 2010
movie,01 Jan 1929
movie,17 Jun 2000
movie,25 Aug 2003
movie,01 May 2008
movie,16 Jul 2004
episode,20 Apr 1980
movie,27 Aug 2013
movie,22 Mar 2009
series,08 Oct 2014
movie,08 Feb 1940
movie,21 Dec 1960
series,07 Sep 1990
movie,24 Mar 1995
movie,24 Nov 2010
movie,10 Mar 2017
series,24 Mar 2017
movie,23 Jul 2002
movie,16 Jan 2004
series,01 Sep 2000
movie,26 Jun 2015
movie,19 Jul 2013
movie,07 Aug 2011
movie,14 Feb 1997
movie,02 Dec 1965
series,17 Jan 2003
movie,16 Mar 1961
movie,08 Mar 1967
movie,02 Apr 1993
movie,06 Jan 1950
series,04 Nov 1955
movie,14 Sep 1955
movie,01 Jul 1975
movie,27 Jun 1979
movie,24 Dec 1970
movie,14 Nov 1941
series,22 Sep 2010
series,30 Oct 1999
movie,23 Feb 1935
movie,31 Jul 1974
movie,01 Jul 2016
movie,14 Apr 1934
movie,22 Mar 1972
movie,24 Jul 1985
movie,21 Dec 1979
movie,21 Jun 2013
series,22 Jan 2001
movie,14 Sep 1975
movie,18 May 1998
movie,01 Aug 1974
movie,09 Jun 1978
movie,15 Aug 2003
movie,25 Aug 2006
movie,22 Aug 2008
movie,14 Dec 1986
movie,16 May 2008
movie,09 Dec 2005
movie,05 Feb 2000
movie,24 Dec 1969
movie,26 Jul 2002
movie,15 Dec 2000
movie,13 Jun 2003
movie,29 Jan 2016
movie,25 Nov 2018
movie,10 Jul 1981
movie,11 Dec 2006
movie,28 Sep 2007
movie,21 Dec 1980
movie,03 Nov 1934
movie,22 Mar 1935
movie,25 Nov 2015
movie,02 Jul 1986
movie,26 Jun 1981
movie,30 Sep 2005
movie,26 Nov 2003
movie,28 Apr 1939
movie,21 Jun 1996
movie,19 Mar 2002
series,12 Nov 2019
episode,13 Aug 2016
movie,20 Nov 1963
movie,05 Nov 2004
movie,27 Sep 1985
movie,18 Oct 1967
movie,14 Feb 2003
movie,28 Sep 1998
movie,31 Mar 2010
movie,05 Dec 2012
movie,19 Jul 2019
movie,10 Feb 2004
movie,27 Oct 1998
movie,24 Jun 1994
movie,17 Nov 1989
movie,19 Sep 2000
movie,25 Aug 2008
movie,10 Nov 1953
movie,02 May 2003
series,17 Oct 2016
movie,04 Mar 2019
movie,13 Mar 1969
series,12 Nov 2019
movie,11 Mar 1977
movie,30 Jun 1971
movie,09 Dec 2012
movie,11 Dec 1992
movie,22 Jun 1979
movie,23 Nov 2011
series,21 Jul 2015
series,17 Jan 1988
movie,01 Aug 1953
movie,15 Aug 2012
movie,05 Nov 1937
movie,09 Oct 1942
movie,13 Feb 1952
movie,08 Sep 2000
movie,21 Jun 1961
movie,29 Jul 1998
movie,16 Sep 1933
episode,31 Oct 1956
movie,14 Sep 2001
movie,06 Jan 1981
movie,16 Nov 1990
movie,11 Dec 2009
movie,09 Oct 1987
movie,03 Aug 2001
movie,11 Aug 2004
series,15 Sep 2001
movie,19 Aug 2005
movie,20 Jun 1941
series,28 Jul 2006
movie,22 Jun 1977
movie,16 Nov 1990
movie,21 Jun 1991
movie,29 Mar 2002
movie,01 May 2007
movie,11 Nov 1994
movie,01 Nov 2002
movie,03 Nov 2006
movie,11 Oct 2002
movie,29 Jun 2007
movie,17 Dec 1976
movie,19 Mar 1959
movie,11 Jun 1960
series,17 Dec 1989
movie,16 Dec 1978
movie,01 Apr 1965
movie,26 Jun 1952
movie,03 Nov 1999
movie,06 Feb 1975
movie,25 Mar 2011
series,18 Mar 2005
series,26 Sep 2008
series,14 Sep 2009
movie,07 Oct 2016
movie,21 Jun 1964
movie,15 May 1999
movie,22 Feb 1945
movie,12 Nov 1993
movie,11 Feb 2000
movie,05 Jan 1935
movie,16 Feb 1966
movie,07 Apr 1939
movie,01 Dec 2000
movie,11 Jul 1955
movie,14 Apr 2006
movie,07 Jun 1934
movie,15 Mar 2013
movie,05 Nov 2019
series,12 Nov 2019
movie,25 Dec 2003
movie,01 Mar 1965
movie,09 Dec 2001
movie,27 May 1933
movie,25 Nov 1987
movie,21 Nov 1990
movie,30 Mar 1994
movie,06 Aug 2004
movie,29 Oct 1993
movie,07 Feb 2020
series,08 Sep 1995
movie,30 Dec 1988
movie,28 Oct 2008
movie,21 Sep 2010
movie,27 Oct 2009
movie,26 Nov 2017
movie,22 Aug 1936
movie,20 Dec 2019
movie,22 Dec 1995
movie,22 Nov 1995
movie,24 Nov 1999
movie,18 Jun 2010
movie,21 Jun 2019
movie,24 Jun 2011
movie,23 Nov 2011
movie,28 Apr 1950
movie,19 Jul 1950
movie,01 Jul 1976
movie,27 Nov 2002
movie,09 Jul 1982
series,20 May 2012
movie,17 Dec 2010
movie,05 Apr 2002
movie,11 Oct 2002
movie,26 Apr 1940
movie,28 Jul 1989
series,24 Mar 2018
movie,07 Dec 2001
movie,14 Oct 2005
movie,12 Oct 2007
movie,26 Jul 1979
series,13 Jan 2012
movie,29 May 2009
movie,22 Jan 2000
movie,19 Aug 2005
movie,07 Jun 2019
series,14 May 2012
movie,06 Oct 2010
movie,27 Jun 2008
movie,26 Jun 1952
movie,16 Jun 2006
movie,10 Mar 2000
movie,18 Jan 1991
movie,22 Jun 1988
series,01 Apr 2012
movie,20 May 1988
movie,22 Nov 2012
movie,15 Jul 2011
movie,12 Nov 2002
movie,09 Mar 2004
movie,03 Jun 1949
series,12 Oct 2007
movie,28 Aug 2009
series,23 Jan 2009
movie,02 Nov 2012
series,04 Nov 2000
series,15 May 2017
movie,01 Jun 1963
movie,27 Jun 1998
movie,10 Jan 2003
movie,06 Nov 2007
movie,16 Feb 2018
movie,23 Jun 2014
movie,23 Jan 1999
movie,12 Jan 2001
movie,11 Jun 2004
movie,04 Mar 2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `disney_movie` and `disney_tv` are empty because categories are `'series'`, and `'movie'`, not `'Series'`, and `'Movie'`.
- You can't make a histogram of a date column, `'released_at'`.
- The data columns should be converted to a `datetime Dtype`, create a new column `'Release Year'`, and then plot a bar plot of the counts for each year.

### Imports and Data

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# load data
df = pd.read_csv('d:/data/kaggle/disney_plus_shows.csv')

# convert the columns to datetime Dtype
df[['released_at', 'added_at']] = df[['released_at', 'added_at']].apply(lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col))

# drop any empty rows
df = df.dropna(subset='released_at')

# create a column for the release year
df['Release Year'] = df.released_at.dt.year

# select the type
data = df[df['type'].isin(['movie', 'series'])]
```

### Plot with [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) and [`kind='hist'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html)

```py
# plot the data
g = sns.displot(data=data, x='Release Year', hue='type', multiple='stack', discrete=True, height=3.5, aspect=2)
```

[image]

### Plot with [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) and [`kind='count'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html)

```py
g = sns.catplot(data=data, x='Release Year', hue='type', kind='count', height=3.5, aspect=3)
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

[image]

### Plot with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and [`kind='bar'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)

- Use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to create a frequency table, and then plot a bar plot of the frequencies.

```py
ct = pd.crosstab(df['Release Year'], df['type'])

ax = ct.plot(kind='bar', y=['movie', 'series'], stacked=True, figsize=(15, 5), width=1, ec='k')
```

[image]