# How do I add a percentage to a countplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, plot-annotations, countplot

I need to show a percentage for my bar graph. However I am not sure how to do it.

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.countplot(y='type',data=df,palette='colorblind')
plt.xlabel('Count')
plt.ylabel('Type')
plt.title('Movie Type in Disney+')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- From `matplotlib v.3.4.0`, the correct way to annotate bars is with the [`.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) method, as thoroughly described in [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804)
- [`seaborn.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) returns `ax : matplotlib.Axes`, so it's customary to us `ax` as the alias for this [axes-level method](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#axes-level-functions-make-self-contained-plots).

  - `Axes` is the [explicit interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface).
- This uses data from your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76184456/7758804).
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
ax = sns.countplot(y='type', data=df, palette='colorblind')

# get the total count of the type column
total = df['type'].count()

# annotate the bars with fmt from matplotlib v3.7.0
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt=lambda x: f'{(x/total)*100:0.1f}%')

# add space at the end of the bar for the labels
ax.margins(x=0.1)

ax.set(xlabel='Count', ylabel='Type', title='Movie Type in Disney+')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- The same implementation also works for vertical bars

```py
ax = sns.countplot(x='type', data=df, palette='colorblind')

# get the total count of the type column
total = df['type'].count()

# annotate the bars with fmt from matplotlib v3.7.0
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt=lambda x: f'{(x/total)*100:0.1f}%')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- `v3.4.0 <= matplotlib < v3.7.0` use the `labels` parameter.

```py
# for horizontal bars
labels = [f'{(w/total)*100:0.1f}%' if (w := v.get_width()) > 0 else '' for v in ax.containers[0]]

# for vertical bars
# labels = [f'{(h/total)*100:0.1f}%' if (h := v.get_height()) > 0 else '' for v in ax.containers[0]]

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=labels)
```

Answer (score 3):

The beginning code looks great! You just have to calculate the percentage values for each bar by dividing the width of the bar by the total count and multiplying by 100. Then use the annotate function to add those values you calculated as text to the bar. Try the code below and see if it works out for you!

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style('whitegrid')

# Create the countplot and naming it 'plot'. 
plot = sns.countplot(y='type', data=df, palette='colorblind')

plt.xlabel('Count')
plt.ylabel('Type')
plt.title('Movie Type in Disney+')

total = len(df['type']) 

for p in plot.patches:
    percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_width() / total)
    x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() + 0.02
    y = p.get_y() + p.get_height() / 2
    plot.annotate(percentage, (x, y))
plt.show()
```